# Why am I being thrown a NullReferenceException when I try to find an element?

Tags: c#, dom, webbrowser-control, nullreferenceexception

I am currently working on a bo that goes in a search bar, selects an element, and gets its `href` link. I am using  the following code and I got  `NullReferenceExceptions` thrown. Does anyone know why?

```
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://us.octobersveryown.com/search?q=shirt");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    String test = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].GetAttribute("class");
```

Thanks,
Nickolas

Comment: Quite probably `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0]` is null. Try to debug your program to verify this.

Comment: @Christos This is all that I am getting:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BlarBot.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: can you post some more code ..

Comment: @user7417866 There isn't any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put that under DocumentCompleted event and access the document in your handle when it fires:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string test = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].GetAttribute("class");
    }
```

Your navigation is not yet loading even though you call the Navigate method. That's why it returns null.